# SQL Server equivalent to Oracle error numbers

Tags: sql-server, oracle, sqlclient

I'm working on a .NET application migration from Oracle to SQL Server database. The application  was developed in the 2000s by a third party, so we intend to modify it as little as possible in order to avoid introducing new bugs.

I replaced the Oracle references to SqlClient ones (`OracleConnection` to `SqlConnection`, `OracleTransaction` to `SqlTransaction` etc.) and everything worked fine. However, I'm having trouble with a logic that tries to reconnect to the DB in case of errors.

If a problem occurs when trying to read/write to the database, method `TryReconnect` is called. This method checks whether the Oracle exception number is 3114 or 12571; if so, it tries to reopen the connection.

I checked these error codes:

- ORA-03114: Not Connected to Oracle
- ORA-12571: TNS: packet writer failure

I searched for the equivalent error codes for SQL Server but I couldn't find them. I checked the [MSSQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/database-engine-events-and-errors?view=sql-server-ver15) and [.NET SqlClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlerror.number?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) documentation but I'm not sure that any of those is equivalent to ORA-3114 and ORA-12571.

Can somebody help me deciding which error numbers should be checked in this logic? I thought about checking for codes 0 (I saw it happen when I stopped the database to force an error and test this) and -2 (Timeout expired), but I'm not really sure about it.

Comment: The behavior is different. You can't base your SQL Server retry logic on Oracle semantics. For starters, [SqlConnection will retry to connect](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/step-4-connect-resiliently-sql-ado-net?view=sql-server-ver15) even in the old `System.Data.SqlClient` library. Its replacement, `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` includes [configurable retry logic](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/azure-sql/configurable-retry-logic-for-microsoft-data-sqlclient/) to handle connections to cloud databases. This retry logic is on by default in the current RTM version , 3.0.0

Comment: You can also look at high-level resiliency libraries like [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly), which offers several retry strategies using policies. [This article describes a SQL Server retry strategies package](https://scottdorman.blog/2020/09/13/database-resiliency-with-polly/) that handles several transient faults. You could use this directly (Polly is *very* popular) or you can handle the transient error numbers described in that article

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior is different. You can't base your SQL Server retry logic on Oracle semantics. For starters, [SqlConnection will retry to connect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/step-4-connect-resiliently-sql-ado-net?view=sql-server-ver15) even in the old System.Data.SqlClient library. Its replacement, [Microsoft.Data.SqlClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient) includes [configurable retry logic](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/azure-sql/configurable-retry-logic-for-microsoft-data-sqlclient/) to handle connections to cloud databases from on-premise applications, eg an on-prem application connecting to Azure SQL.  This retry logic is on by default in the current RTM version , 3.0.0.

You can also look at high-level resiliency libraries like [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly), a very popular resiliency package that implements recovery strategies like retries with backoff, circuit breakers etc. [This article](https://scottdorman.blog/2020/09/13/database-resiliency-with-polly/) describes [Cadru.Polly](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Cadru.Polly/) which contains strategies for handling several SQL Server transient faults. You could use this directly  or you can handle the transient error numbers described in that article:

| Exception Handling Strategy | Errors Handled |
| --- | --- |
| SqlServerTransientExceptionHandlingStrategy | 40501, 49920, 49919, 49918, 41839, 41325, 41305, 41302, 41301, 40613, 40197, 10936, 10929, 10928, 10060, 10054, 10053, 4221, 4060, 12015, 233, 121, 64, 20 |
| SqlServerTransientTransactionExceptionHandlingStrategy | 40549, 40550 |
| SqlServerTimeoutExceptionHandlingStrategy | -2 |
| NetworkConnectivityExceptionHandlingStrategy | 11001 |

Polly allows you to combine policies and specify different retry strategies for them, eg :

- Using a cached response in some cases (lookup data?)
- Retrying with backoff (even random delays) in other cases (deadlocks?). Random delays can be *very* useful if you run into timeouts because too many concurrent operations cause deadlocks or timeouts. Without it, all failing requests would retry at the same time, causing yet another failure
- Using a circuit breaker to switch to a different service or server.

You could create an Oracle strategy so you can use Polly throughout your projects and handle all recoverable failures, not just database retries.